# Compare two JTextFields

Tags: java

I am trying this one but it gives an error.

```
if(jTextField1.getText().equals("1") && jTextField2.getText().compareToIgnoreCase("1")!))
```

please suggest me how can i compare both text fields to check the condition if(1st not equals to 2nd). Thanks!

Comment: This will work `if(!jTextField1.getText().equals(jTextField2.getText()))`

Comment: #Jyothi Thank you Very Much

Comment: it is working  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(jTextField1.getText().equals(jTextField2.getText()))
{
//both text fields have same text
}

else
{
// both text fields have different text

}
```